# How to remove password lock on WD mybook 1TB

Tags: password-recovery, portable-harddrive

How do I disable the password lock on my My book 1 TB, I want to so I may use it directly with my xbox 360, since it won't pick it up on my pc list.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with my 4TB WD My Book external drive and I did the following:

1. Download and install WD Security from http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?DL
2. Plug your external hard hard drive to your computer and unlock it with the password
3. Run the WD Security application
4. Select the "Remove password" and type in your password and then click on the button that says <kbd>Update Security Settings</kbd> as shown in the picture below:
   [image: WD Security password removal steps]

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear, has the password been set, and you forgot it?

http://community.wdc.com/t5/External-Drives-for-Mac/WD-My-Book-1TB-locked-out/td-p/6860 states the following:

> 1. Unplug and plug in Drive again.
> 2. You will be prompted to type in password.
> 3. Type five wrong password.
> 4. After 5th time, you will be prompted with screen to check off and
>      give your drive storage back in
>      exchange of giving up data.  *** There
>      is no way to get password back (no
>      exception; not even from WD)***

Or look for the user guide here
http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=1&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

This came to the front page, so I'll reply, but the OP probably wiped it already.

See if you had installed anything from a CD **originally** to enable this password set-up. You should summon the same program to seek the option to change the known password to an empty one. If you don't remember the original password, then you will have to clean-wipe it.

My best guess is that the PC list means your "My Computer" list of disks. If it used to just be there originally and *suddenly disappeared*, you have a disk problem totally unrelated to passwords. Then I would recommend running the original CD's recovery programs (or use the Moab's links and download anything that looks useful for your exact WD model.)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove password permanently using **WD Discovery** *utility* as follows.

1. [Download WD Discovery](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=293&lang=en) according to your OS
2. Install the utility on the PC or Server
3. Open WD Discovery from system tray icon
4. Go to Storage tab
5. Unlock the Drive from drive list
6. Go to the option right clicking on the wheel icon on the drive
7. Click Remove password

**Note:** *Never remove the drive while unlocking the drive.*